# Parallel vectors depiction accuracy

Tags: vectors

Given that $\vec{BC} = -\frac{2}{5} \vec{AB}$

Would you consider the below depiction as inaccurate? [image]

Comment: I would not.  $\vec {AB}$ and $\vec {BC}$ should be parallel.  You also don't have the arrows on $\vec {AB}$ or $\vec {BC}$.  Are you sure this is the right picture?

Comment: If they are to be parallel, you would.

Comment: $\vec {BC}$ should also be a little less than half the size of $\vec{AB}$, which it doesn't look like here.  So, no.  Just making them parallel wouldn't completely fix it either.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was going for. I was stumped for a moment there when looking at this picture

Comment: are a and b directions ?

Comment: They are vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to draw $$\vec {BC} = -\frac 25\vec{AB}$$

[image]

I drew $\vec {AB}$ a little to the side so that it wasn't overtop $\vec{BC}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks :)

Comment: I doubt that a and b are not the directions like $$\vec{a}$$ What if they are representing any natural number variable.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Given $\vec {BC}=-\frac{2}{5}\vec{AB}$ represents that the vectors $\vec {BC}$ & $\vec {AB}$ should be anti-parallel to each other (i.e. parallel to each other & in opposite directions) but the diagram shows them nonparallel/intersecting so the depiction is not correct.

Comment: Yeap, thanks again Harish!